# Binding to (possibly) null property in code not updating ModelView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a binding to a Singleton property that looks like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SourceList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MySingleton.Instance}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                      Path=PossibleNullProperty.PossibleNullProperty.PossibleNullProperty.Source}" 
                                      Width="Auto" />
```

This works very well and even if the PossibleNullProperty is null, as soon as they change, the 'Source' property is binded to the ComboBox.

Now I have also a Command Binding in my ModelView which binds to a DelegateCommand in the ViewModel. As soon as the SelectedItem changes, the DelegateCommand should raise the CanExecuteChangedEvent.

Well I can't raise this event in the Object where the 'Source' property is. 
So I have to raise this event in the ViewModel. 
My Idea was to create a property which points to the nested property like this:

```
public string Source
    {
        get { return MySingleton.Instance.PossibleNullProperty?.PossibleNullProperty?.PossibleNullProperty?.Source; }
        set
        {
            MySingleton.Instance.PossibleNullProperty.PossibleNullProperty.PossibleNullProperty.Source = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
            MyCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is, at the time when the Binding occurs, a property in the chain is null so the ComboBox SelectedItem can't "reach" the 'Source' property. 
During the Application Runtime, this can change and the 'Source' property is "reachable", but the ModelView doesn't get updated.

How can I achieve a solution for my problem?

Thanks

Comment: Put all the data required for your view into your view model (or code behind).

Comment: But what if the Nested Property changes, so I have to subscribe to the PropertyChanged event in the whole chain and when the property changes, I have to set the new value in my ViewModel...

Comment: In a simplest approach you have to ensure that every type in the properties' chain implements INotifyPropertyChanged and exposes the MySingleton as property on your VM, while the binding path will be the whole path from MySingleton to the required property. Otherwise you are to listen to each property's notifications in some way.

Comment: Every object in the whole chain implements INotifyPropertyChanged, but what do you mean with 'exposes the MySingleton as property on your VM'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your ViewModel and you will do fine:

```
    CommandManager.RequerySuggested += CommandManager_RequerySuggested;

    private void CommandManager_RequerySuggested(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.MyCommand.CanExecute = "..." 
    }
```

CommandManager_RequerySuggested will be called for every change in UI!!!!

Since this event is static, it will only hold onto the handler as a weak reference.

Dont forget to use async/await :)

Comment: Hi, this solved my problem partly, the CanExecuteChangedEvent will be called, but the Binding does not update, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You asked how to trigger CanExecute from ViewModel. That is how :) If you wish binding to know when static property changed I suggest to you to take a look how to bind to static property properly. http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/28/wpf-4-5-%E2%80%93-part-9-binding-to-static-properties/

Comment: Nevermind, the solution works, I just had to delete the property which points to the nested property and make the Binding directly to the Singleton again. Thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

For people with the same problem, this is how my DelegateCommand class looks now and it works perfectly thanks for the solution of dev hedgehog!

```
public class DelegateCommand<T> : System.Windows.Input.ICommand where T : class
{
    private readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<T> _execute;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null)
            return true;

        return _canExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute((T)parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}
```